# Interrupt handler chaining in real mode

Tags: c, assembly, interrupt-handling, tasm, real-mode

I'm trying to hook BIOS Int 13h to add my custom functionality to it and hijack some of existing one.
Old Int 13h vector is stored in global variable.
When interrupt handler is called the DS is set to some value that doesn't match the original data segment of caller. Therefore accessing global variables of caller turns into a headache.

What is best practice to chain interrupt handlers?

Hook is installed this way:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#  define INTARGS ...
#else
#  define INTARGS unsigned bp, unsigned di, unsigned si,\
                  unsigned ds, unsigned es, unsigned dx,\
                  unsigned cx, unsigned bx, unsigned ax
#endif

void interrupt (far *hackInt13h)(INTARGS) = NULL;
void interrupt (far *biosInt13h)(INTARGS) = (void interrupt (far *)(INTARGS))0xDEADBEEF;

void main(void)
{
  struct REGPACK reg;

  biosInt13h = getvect(0x13);
  hackInt13h = int13h;

  setvect(0x13, hackInt13h);

  // Calling CAFE
  reg.r_ax = 0xCAFE;
  intr(0x13, &reg);
  printf("Cafe returned: 0x%04x\n", reg.r_ax);

  // Resetting FDD just to check interrupt handler chaining
  reg.r_ax = 0;
  reg.r_dx = 0;
  intr(0x13, &reg);
  printf("CF=%i\n", reg.r_flags & 0x01);

  setvect(0x13, biosInt13h);
}
```

Int 13h hook code:

```
    P286
    .MODEL TINY

_Data   SEGMENT PUBLIC 'DATA'
    EXTRN _biosInt13h:FAR
_Data   ENDS


_Text   SEGMENT PUBLIC 'CODE'
    PUBLIC _int13h
_int13h PROC FAR
    pusha
    cmp AX,0CAFEh
    jnz chain
    popa
    mov AX, 0BEEFh
    iret
chain:
    popa
    call    far ptr [_biosInt13h]   ; <-- at this moment DS points to outer space
                                    ;     and _biosInt13h is not valid
_int13h ENDP
_Text   ENDS
    END
```

I'm using Borland C++ if it matters

Comment: Set up `ds` to point to `_Data` of course. Restore it before chaining or returning. You can't chain with a `call far` because the original handler ends with an `iret` too.

Comment: The usual solution is to either move the variable into the code segment so you can use `call far ptr [cs:_biosInt13h]` or to set up the segments as needed, retrieve the pointer, place it on the stack, restore segments, and then do a `retf` to jump to the BIOS interrupt handler.  Note that the code will crash as-is because an interrupt handler pops off flags in addition to a return address.

Comment: If you're using tiny model you can use a `cs` segment override with the far call. However, you either need to change it to a far jump, or add `pushf` before the far call.

Comment: `_int13h PROC FAR` is also going to put the wrong return instruction so you need an explicit `iret` after the `pushf` \ `call far`.

Comment: I'm not going to return to my handler after chaining so I have no chance to restore DS.
Moving ```_biosInt13h``` into code segment and then pushing old handler address on stack and ```retf``` looks like hack but certainly works. Quite a good idea.

Comment: If you aren't returning to your handler and are tail calling the old one then you can just use `jmp far ptr [cs:_biosInt13h]` . Then the `iret` will be done directly by the old interrupt handler.

Comment: The CS segment override will only work if you are doing this in the tiny model and ultimately build a COM program otherwise you would have to explicitly load the DS register with the segment specific to the model you are using.

Comment: @MichaelPetch  You just need to put the variable in the same segment as the interrupt function that accesses it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I've found solution!

First thing I've missed is moving variable to code segment and explicitly specifying it.

Second one is using hacked (pushed on stack) return address and `retf` instead of `call` that adds real return address on stack.

No need to `pushf` explicitly 'cause flags are already on stack after `int`. And flags will be popped on `iret` no matter in my handler or in chained one.

```
    P286
    .MODEL TINY

_Text   SEGMENT PUBLIC 'CODE'
    EXTRN _biosInt13h:FAR ; This should be in CODE 'cause CS is only segreg reliable
    PUBLIC _int13h
_int13h PROC FAR
    pusha
    cmp AX, 0CAFEh
    jnz chain
    popa
    mov AX, 0BEEFh
    iret
chain:
    popa
    push    word ptr cs:[_biosInt13h + 2]   ; Pushing chained handler SEG on stack
    push    word ptr cs:[_biosInt13h]       ; Pushing chained handler OFFSET on stack
    retf                        ; ...actually this is JMP FAR to address on stack
_int13h ENDP
_Text   ENDS
    END
```

Comment: Why the `push` `push` `retf`. Can't you just do an indirect far jump. Trying to remember TASM's syntax for that. Maybe `jmp dword ptr cs:[_biosInt13h]` ?

Comment: You can write just `jmp [_biosInt13h]` instead of the RETF stuff, but you need to declare `_biosInt13h` correctly as `EXTERN _biosInt13h:DWORD` and you need to tell the assembler it can't assume DS and ES point to the same segment as `_TEXT` with `ASSUME DS:NOTHING, ES:NOTHING`.

Comment: @MichaelPetch also works. ```push``` ```push``` ```retf``` was inspired by disassembly of MS-DOS 5.0 boot record.

Comment: @RossRidge far pointer has same size as DWORD but it seems better to use appropriate types instead ones of same length.
So I prefer ```jmp far ptr``` to ```jmp dword ptr```

Comment: No, the appropriate type for a far pointer is DWORD..  FAR is the appropriate type for a far label you would jump to directly.  DWORD is the appropriate type for a far pointer you would jump to indirectly.  To make it clear I'm saying you should not be using `jmp far ptr` as that would be a direct jump, and you don't need to use `jmp dword ptr` if you declare `_biosInt13h` correctly.   DWORD and FAR are both the same size, but are not interchangeable when used with jump and call instructions.  DWORD is the type you need to use to get an indirect jump.